# Formula to work out the number of answers in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula to work out the number of answers in a single cell. Each line in entered with ALT+Enter.

Column A is imported data and Column B is the result.

[Sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJntG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an Excel function to count occurrences of a certain characters in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128337/is-there-an-excel-function-to-count-occurrences-of-a-certain-characters-in-a-cel)

Comment: You just need to count the number of `ALT-ENTER`'s in a cell, and add 1

Answer (score 0):

J Lange,
You can use the below formula in B2 and copy the same in all other cells.

```
=IF(TRIM(A2)="",0,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1)
```