# Excel formula for checking letters and counting the words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I have a list of words and I would like to see if a certain letter exists in these words and if yes, then how many words have this letter?

Example:

```
abdications 
abdominally
abecedarian
aberrancies
```

Result:

```
A: 4
B: 4
C: 3
D: 3
E: 2
F: 0
```

and so on.

I have tried the following formula, but it counts the total amount of letters:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(Range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Range,Letter,"")))
```

Result:

```
A: 9
B: 4
C: 3
D: 3
E: 4
F: 0
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58805128/edit) to let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an Excel function to count occurrences of a certain characters in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128337/is-there-an-excel-function-to-count-occurrences-of-a-certain-characters-in-a-cel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(Range,"*"&Letter&"*")
```

Comment: Back from vacation I see :)

Comment: @SJR I always use COUNTIFS() because I constantly start thinking only one criteria just to have another pop up as I am typing the formula, it is habit.

Comment: Fair enough. I was overthinking it and came up with an array formula.